# how to enable only checkbox enabled fields in the fieldset

Tags: jquery

```
$('#btnCancel').click(function() {

         $('fieldset:not(:checked)').find("input,select,textarea").removeAttr('disabled');
        });
```

how to enable only checked boxes? on the fieldsset? but when I do this code its enabling all my fields in the fieldset I need to enable only the fields which checkbox is enabled?

thanks

Comment: http://www.annedorko.com/blog/toggle-enable-and-disable-a-form-field-with-a-checkbox-javascript-101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('fieldset').find('input:not(:checked),select,textarea').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: buts its doing only for that input box not for all select and textarea ?

Comment: Select and Textarea elements shouldn't have a 'checked' attribute.  You could try `$('fieldset').find('input,select,textarea').filter(':not(:checked)').removeAttr('disabled');` I suppose, but those other elements shouldn't have a checked attribute to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for fieldsets that are not checked using the code you've posted. You'll want to apply the "not checked" logic to the `input`, `select` and `textarea` tags instead.